# SFML drawing a shape to multiple places on the screen

Tags: c++, drawing, sfml

What I want to do is to draw a Rectangle Shape object to multiple places on the screen and have them all displayed. I tried doing this:

```
window.draw(rectangle);
rectangle.setPosition(100, 200);
window.draw(rectangle);
window.display();
```

But it only displayed the second rectangle. Is there any easy solution to this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Are you setting the position of the first rectangle? You don't need two rectangles objects to achieve two visual rectangles. Try to set the position of one rectangle, draw it, set the position to the new location, and draw that again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it working :D
I didn't think you would have to set the position of the first rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code should work fine. I think the fact is that you set the position of your rectangle to `100, 200` but you never set it back to whatever position the first one is before drawing it again.
You should have

```
window.clear();
rectangle.setPosition(0.f, 0.f);
window.draw(rectangle);
rectanlge.setPosition(100.f, 200.f);
window.draw(rectangle);
window.display();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Have two rectangles with different positions. Draw both, then `display()`.